# Html label input tag using id doesn't work properly

Tags: html, label, bootstrap-5

I am new to Html/CSS.
This is my signup.html file

#### Signup.html

```html
<div class="form-floating">
    <select name="phone_number_0" class="form-control" required="" id="id_phone_number_0"><option value="">---------</option>
    <option value="+93">Afghanistan +93</option><option value="+355">Albania +355</option>
    </select>
    <input type="text" name="phone_number_1" class="form-control" required="" id="id_phone_number_1">
    <label for="id_phone_number_0">Country code:</label>
    <label for="id_phone_number_1">Phone number</label>
</div>
```

The output look like this

[image: Both label collapsed together]

**What is the reason for this? I gave different `id`s, I am using Bootstrap5 classes**

Answer (score 0):

Use a `<div>` for separate the input and put `label` before `input` like:

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div class="form-floating">
  <div>
    <label for="id_phone_number_0">Country code:</label>
    <select name="phone_number_0" class="form-control" required="" id="id_phone_number_0">
      <option value="">---------</option>
      <option value="+93">Afghanistan +93</option>
      <option value="+355">Albania +355</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div>
    <label for="id_phone_number_1">Phone number</label>
    <input type="text" name="phone_number_1" class="form-control" required="" id="id_phone_number_1">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I see, but the problem is I am doing these in django, and django automatically renders **dropdown and input field** together, I don't have control over that part. I am using **PhoneNumberPrefixWidget** from **django-phonenumber-field** library